# Change to DOM item isn't retained after event handler ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stumped. After any radio button is clicked, I'm checking the value of a hidden variable to determine if I should display an error message, which is initially empty. (I added debugging alerts to follow the behavior.)

When the variable is 1 and it enters the if clause, I get the first alert and close it, and the error message displays properly. I get the second alert, and then after closing it, the function ends and the error message is empty again -- as if I executed the line `$("#submitmessage").html("")`.

```
$("input").change(function(){
    if ($("#errorCheck").val() == "1") {
        alert("Debug check - before");
        $('#submitmessage').addClass('errorMessage');
        $("#submitmessage").html("My error message...");
        alert("Debug check - after");
        return false;
    } else {  ...
```

I've tried stopping propogation, returning true and false, not returning anything -- nothing helps.

Comment: You are selecting all inputs, including the radio button. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: D'oh! I just found it.  I had another conflicting handler that deleted it.  Thanks for the quick response!